# Python not collecting data from Arduino correctly (need help syncing)

Tags: python, arduino, synchronization

I need help getting my Arduinos output to sync up with Python. I'm using arduinos analogue output connected up to some photodiodes to track an LED by checking the voltage at each photodiode then outputting this into python to be processed. Currently my code is as follows:

```
//Arduino
float A0vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A1vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A2vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A3vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A4vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A5vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A6vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A7vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A8vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A9vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A10vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A11vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A12vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A13vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A14vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float A15vo = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float VT = 0; // variale to store the total value of the voltages from the sensors
float POS = 0; // variable to store the position coeficient of the LED
float FP = 0; // variable to store the final position of the LED
float ZP = 0.52; // change for zero position
float cal[16] = {-24, -21, -18, -15, -12, -9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21}; //calibration array to corresponding photodiodes position in cm

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200); // set baud rate
}

void loop() {
  // read the value from the sensor:
  A0vo = analogRead(A0); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A1vo = analogRead(A1); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A2vo = analogRead(A2); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A3vo = analogRead(A3); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A4vo = analogRead(A4); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A5vo = analogRead(A5); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A6vo = analogRead(A6); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A7vo = analogRead(A7); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A8vo = analogRead(A8); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A9vo = analogRead(A9); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A10vo = analogRead(A10); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A11vo = analogRead(A11); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A12vo = analogRead(A12); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A13vo = analogRead(A13); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A14vo = analogRead(A14); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  A15vo = analogRead(A15); // extract voltage at given photodiode
  VT = (A0vo + A1vo + A3vo + A4vo + A5vo + A6vo + A7vo + A8vo + A9vo + A10vo + A11vo + A12vo + A13vo + A14vo + A15vo); // populate total voltage variable
  POS = (A0vo*cal[0] + A1vo*cal[1] + A2vo*cal[2] + A3vo*cal[3] + A4vo*cal[4] + A5vo*cal[5] + A6vo*cal[6] + A7vo*cal[7] + A8vo*cal[8] + A9vo*cal[9] + A10vo*cal[10] + A11vo*cal[11] + A12vo*cal[12] + A13vo*cal[13] + A14vo*cal[14] + A15vo*cal[15]); // populate position coefficent variable
  FP = (POS/VT); // calculate final position
//

  Serial.println(FP+ZP);
delay(10); // set loop delay 1000=1sec for aquistion
}
```

and

```
#Python

import serial
import time
import numpy as np
import sys

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 19200, timeout=0) #config serial port to read


outpl = []
outp = []
outp2 = []
outp3 = []
outp4 = []

TI = 10 #time for data collection to continue for in seconds

t_start = time.time()
t_end = time.time() + TI
while time.time() < t_end:
    try:
        outp = ser.read(3) #reads serial port
        outp2 = np.array([float(i) for i in((outp.decode('utf-8'))).split(',')]) #decodes and prints data
        outp4 = ','.join(str(e) for e in outp2) #converts to pastable format 
        outpl.append(outp2) #
        print(outp4)
        print((int(((time.time()-t_start)/((time.time()+TI)-t_start))*200)), end="\r") #loading in %
        time.sleep(0.01)
    except ValueError: #checks for errors
        pass

print('DONE!')
ser.close() #close serial
```

It works fine when I'm taking 10 or less data points per second, but I need roughly 100 points per second!

Sample of Arduinos serial monitor:

```
-5.06
-4.75
-4.35
-3.93
-3.56
-3.15
-2.84
-2.49
-2.17
-1.91
-1.55
-1.21
-0.98
-0.65
-0.42
-0.19
0.09
0.41
0.72
1.08
1.51
1.91
2.30
2.67
3.17
3.60
4.17
4.85
5.44
```

Sample of Pythons output:

```
0.0
0.4
7.0
0.0
0.42
10.0
35.0
0.0
0.2
9.0
0.0
0.24
10.0
15.0
0.0
0.0
7.0
0.0
95.0
0.0
0.74
9.5
3.0
0.0
26.0
0.0
0.04
8.8
0.0
0.0
49.0
0.0
0.22
7.9
2.0
0.0
66.0
```

I'm guessing I need to somehow sync them both, but I am not sure on how to do that at all! Any help is appreciated as I'm pretty new to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Which Arduino are you using? Most have a processor speed of 16MHz, but the ESP32 and a few others are capable of ~100-200MHz. If you need to sample 16 pins at 100 points per second, that may be maxing out the processor. You can test by splitting the readings between two different Arduinos and seeing what the max sampling rate you can achieve is.

Answer (score 0):

With this line `outp = ser.read(3) #reads serial port` you are reading 3 bytes of data for each loop. Are you sure that the data you are sending from the arduino are no more than that?

Maybe try with `ser.readline()` which will ensure that you are reading a terminated line instead?

Hope it helps,